# How to avoid and What to do with OPs moving the goalposts in the comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

An annoying behaviour that wastes time and effort are *comments that shift the goalpost* after receiving an answer. Sometimes the cause is an incomplete explanation of their needs and some other times the OP is just requesting new "features" that may render inappropriate a particular strategy already developed in the answer.

**What should we do to avoid shifting sands comments?**

**How do we deal with them without appearing as attacking the OP?**

It's frustrating to contribute effort to a specific question to then see contradictory details or new requests not previously mentioned in the question.

**I wonder if new users could be confronted with a checklist** while editing their questions, designed to prevent this and other poor questions. Is that technically feasible?

Current tips seems insufficient

[image]

Comment: Could we require the  **Informed** badge before allowing posting questions?
Unfortunately there is no mention in the [tour] of any of the good practices the are considered almost mandatory before asking, such as searching the site and the documentation, sharing formatted code and data, etc.

Comment: SE tries to keep the entry barrier as low as possible.  People don't even need to register to ask. I think they'd never agree to requiring a badge ...

Comment: Once I got so irritated at the frequency of this that I copied a remark into my SE scratch notebook for easy pasting: "It's bad form to alter a question so much. You make the answers and work others have done on your behalf seem irrelevant. SE is not a private consulting service but a public Q&A forum. Please, either ask the question you need to ask the first time, or ask a new question." The wording might need changing since the situation you describe does not seem exactly the same.  But I think such an "attack" is ok. The 3rd line might be unnecessary, but on the whole it's not unkind.

Comment: I'm entirely with you on the checklist! Just avoiding  the questions destined for math.stackexchange.com would save so much hassle.

Comment: [A related meta.SE question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe it could be better if your comment is set in a more respectful tone. Perhaps starting it with "Dear Mr. Moron"

Comment: @Dr.belisarius but to account for all eventualities, "Dear Dr./Mr. Moron" may be advisable.

Comment: can we try and draw some conclusions? Is implementing the checklist something technically possible on StackExchange? Is there any other solution?

Comment: @rhermans See my comment here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108616/193 :)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/handling-questions-and-associated-answers-when-question-is-fundamentally-changed