# Our 'How to Ask' sidebar

Tags: discussion, status-completed

In [this meta question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/3066), rhermans showed our current 'How to Ask' sidebar and commented: Current tips seems insufficient.

I must admit that the sidebar had become invisible to me. Now that I have been made aware of it again, I could not agree more. In fact, I'd go a lot further and say I think it would totally confuse me were I a first-time user of *Mathematica*.SE. I would very much like to see us improve upon it.

The sidebar closely follows the 'How to Ask' sidebar of [*StackOverflow.SE*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I worry that means its content is largely dictated by stack exchange.com, meaning that we have little or no control over it. Is that the case?

Just so you don't have bring up another page to see the current sidebar.

[image: sidebar]

#### Edit

This is in response to J.M.'s comments.

- I was afraid no-local-control would be the case. My main gripe concerning the current tips is that they are too concise to convey much of what a new-comer needs to know.
- I have posted my sidebar revisions as a community wiki answer as you have suggested.

---

### Edit by J. M.:

As a heads-up: the highest voted proposal by next Tuesday (May 30) will be the one I'll submit to SE staff for inclusion in our sidebar.

Comment: AFAICT, mods do not have the ability to edit that sidebar. If y'all have any suggestions on what should be in there (concise yet informative, if you please), post 'em here.

Comment: Why not put your proposed sidebar text as a (CW?) answer, so that it can be voted on, or maybe even edited, as seen fit.

Comment: Good news: SE is willing to edit the "How to Ask" sidebar text, once we've agreed on what we want in it. So, vote for the ones you like, or propose your own in an answer.

Comment: @rhermans, that's why I'm trying to give plenty of time for people to look before I ping the SE guys, as well as making an announcement over at chat. I think your current answer can stand.

Comment: There are two answers with 7 points. Extend the period?

Comment: I think extending the period for another week would be a good idea.

Comment: I think time is up. The result is a clear majority (8 points vs 6, 3 and 1) for the answer by MichaelE2. 
 There has not been any activity by @J.M. since May 26. I hope everything is fine.

Answer (score 10):

- **Is your question about how to use the software [Wolfram *Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)?**
- [Search the site.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search) [Look up it in *Mathematica's* documentation center.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/)  Then ask.
- We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
- If your question is about this website, [**ask it on meta**](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: When I put the first question as a comment, the user always gets it.  I think "about Mathematica" is easily mistranslated or misread as "about Mathematics," since mathematica is Latin for mathematics. Nonetheless...

Comment: ...my tendency is to ignore all sidebars when I visit a site.  Eventually I might notice them, if I seem to be failing at getting the site to work for me.  I don't see why having all the answers there is going to cure such careless behavior.  And as a teacher who has observed the behavior of undergraduates for many years, I feel I am not alone.

Comment: These appear to shorter, snappier versions of four of my points. Definitely an improvement. Much more likely to be read than my tl;dr list.

Comment: @rhermans As my previous comment might suggest, I have weak faith in instructions to begin with, and their efficacy varies inversely with their length, imo. I think the points in your answer are common, important issues; indeed, they're my pet peeves, and I could include more ("Keep in mind people are volunteering to help you -- make it easy for them!"). But I'm inclined to think they're not helpful in the sidebar. Perhaps the link called "asking help" could be highlighted/emphasized: "If in doubt, read *asking help*." It helps to have such rules written down as a reference for those who err.

Comment: @rhermans I'm not sure.  Probably need to ask a moderator.

Comment: I could see something like this as another bullet point: "If in doubt, see the full [How to Ask](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [On Topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages."

Comment: @rhermans See if that works...

Answer (score 7):

- **Be on-topic**, only questions about Wolfram Mathematica programming.
- **Be diligent**, before asking search the site and Mathematica documentation.
- **Be specific**, include working code and data in formatted form, ask distinct answerable questions, give brief context.
- **Don’t move the goalpost**, stick to your original question. If you need more,
  then ask another question.
- **Keep the site useful**, make your question relevant for other readers, edit to correct mistakes when you can.

---

It would look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have edited the answer to unlock the votes and make the text briefer.

Comment: The amount of questions that are *off-topic* because they should be in **meta** is too small compared to the huge number of questions of people failing to be **diligent** and **specific**. Therefore, I'm intentionally leaving the *"ask it on meta"* out.

Answer (score 2):

- Only questions about Wolfram Research Inc.'s Mathematica software belong on this website.
- Please take the time to look in the Mathematica documentation before asking here.
- This is not a discussion forum. Do not post general, open-ended, or wide-ranging questions.
- We will not do your homework nor your work place assignment. We *will* give help on particular points of difficulty. Be as specific as you can.
- Do not leave out important details from your question. Do not include unnecessary ones. Keep in mind that people reading your question don't know anything about your Mathematica work that you don't tell them.
- If your question is about how to use this website, ask your question on Meta.Mathematica, not this site.

Comment: @rhermans. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2160/8461) with a small change (to make two links distinct):

[image: Updated How to Ask]

Please let me know if there are any typos or other problems.

Comment: "up" and "it" got interchanged in the second sentence; thus "Look it up in *Mathematica*'s documentation center."

Comment: @J.M.: Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How to Ask

**Is your question about [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)?**

We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.

Provide details. Share your research. A minimum working example increases the likelihood of good responses

If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Except for the change of Mathematica to Wolfram Mathematica, I do not believe that the current text needs any alterations. People are not going to read a wall of text, so it's more important to keep it short and simple than to list every possible criticism. In fact, preemptively bringing up criticism creates a bad atmosphere.

Comment: Except, perhaps, 'A minimum working example increases the likelihood of good responses'

Comment: @tomd Yes, I'll put that in there as well. That's a good idea.